# How to communicate with UI thread efficiently in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, networking, ui-thread

I am not good in Android techniques that is why I post a question.

Remote server sends pics to the Android-device over TCP connection with high frequency (up to 30 fps). Android device is to fetch pics and display them in ImageView container (simulating video).

Cause UI manipulation is only allowed from main thread I got some performance issues. Now network receive operation is running in a single thread, which moves data to UI thread on each received pic according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html#Handler).

I got two ideas to better performance:

1. Skip some pics (UI thread updates itself and takes the newest frame from some resource shared with networking thread)
2. Somehow optimize drawing process (now I simply assign a Bitmap to the ImageView)

Due to poor Android experience I can't determine whether this ideas are appreciated. So any suggestions are welcome.
Thx.

Comment: Maybe a second thread that reads from a ConcurrentLinkedQueue or any other thread safe queue and posts the polled images into your view?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re it might be a good idea (I was considering own implementation of thread-safe queue) and I shall test its performance.
But I think that the real milestone is in way of drawing image on screen (now I build a Bitmap from raw jpeg/png/bmp data and assign it to ImageView).

Comment: If you have control over the server, I would stream it as video over UDP.

Comment: @nasch
Though UDP is preferable for real-time traffic I use TCP (cause messaging framework I use doesn't support UDP).

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but I can't see how multithreading will get you a better (useful) performance. I suggest you to reduce the image or encode (in the source) and then revert - decode (on receiver). One place to go is here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer.html

But you must ask yourself about the images, the sizes, if you have a big image, you really need it ? You did not talk about it, it's important in most cases. This parameters like size matters. This article could help you if this is a good option for you: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Sure image is encoded on server and than decoded on receiver.
And I realize that image size matters, but LAN connection allows transfer enough data for 30+ fps while UI can't display more than 12-15 fps.

Multi-threading is required, just because network connection can't be established in main (UI) thread.